# Adding id's to comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie here. A seemingly simple issue has me stuck. I am unable to view the comments#show page. I think it is because my comments don't have individual id's. I added comment_id to my comments table with no success. I'm getting the following error:

```
No route matches missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here is my comments#index file:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
<div>
<strong><td><%= link_to (comment.title), post_comment_path(@post) %></strong>
<%= comment.subtitle %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my migration for adding a comment_id column:

```
rails generate migration AddComment_idToComments comment_id:integer
```

My routes.rb file:

```
resources :posts do

 resources :comments
 resources :pictures
end

devise_for :users
root to: 'posts#index'
match '/about', to: 'pages#about',  via:'get'
```

Here is my comments table:

```
create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "post_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "title"
t.string   "subtitle"
t.string   "body"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "comment_id"
end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you please post your routes.rb it should be `post_comments_path(:id => @post.id)` or `post_comment_path(:id => @post.id)`

Comment: Yes, routes.rb added.

Comment: check your `post_comment_path` use `rake routes`

Comment: The post_comment_path is the comments#show path.

Comment: `post_comment_path(:id => comment.id)` can you please try this

Comment: Both yours and @h4pless 's solutions worked. I appreciate the help!

Comment: ok may I make a post of it so that you can vote me up please...?

Comment: I don't have a high enough reputation to vote you up right now. I definitely will once i do though (6 more to go!)

Comment: I have voted most of your post ....carry on...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ask why you have a single @post variable in your comments index but assuming that your code is creating a list of links, to make them point to each individual comment's show action I believe you are looking for:

`<%= link_to comment.title, comment %>`

Also, you have a rogue `<td>` tag in there that's going to mess up the rendering in the comments index.

In addition, unless you have explicitly set the id to false in the migration when you created the model, it has an id by default that acts as its primary key. If you did set the id to false when you created the model you can add it back by running a migration on the table with

`add_column :comments, :id, :primary_key`

but assuming you did not set `:id => false` in your original migration, then it already has an id that you can access with `comment.id`, this is how the `Comment.find(params[:id])` that you most likely in your Comments#show action works.

Comment: Now that gives me an 'undefined method 'comment_path'' error.

Comment: What do you get if you run `rake routes` from the command line? Do you have `resources :comments` in your config/routes.rb file?

Comment: Yes resources :comments is inside resources :posts in my routes.rb. I just added my routes.rb to the question if you want to take a look.

Comment: Scratch that, I see your routes.rb file now, just move a copy of the `resources :comments` line outside of the `resources :posts do` section with the above code.

Comment: Or without changing the routes file you should be able to make the link work with `post_comment_path(@post, comment)`

Comment: For more information on rails routing let me introduce you to your new best friend, [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects).

Comment: That seems to have worked! Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have defined the relationship between a post and a comment such that a post *has many*  comments or a comment *belongs to* a post.  Your `comments` table needs a field called `id` and another field called `post_id`, assuming again that the table that contains the posts is called `posts` and the model is named `Post`.

This lets a comment reference the post that it belongs to. For example let's say you had this post:

```
------------------------
| id | title | content |
| -- | ----- | ------- |
| 24 | Lorem | Ipsum   |
------------------------
```

Now a comment can attach itself to this post by using the `post_id` field:

```
-----------------------------------
| id | post_id | title | subtitle |
| -- | ------- | ----- | -------- |
| 19 | 24      | Lorem | Ipsum    |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Rails is convention-based. It expects every table to have an identifier named `id`.

Comment: I'm trying to add an id column but am getting a 'duplicate column name: id' error. Is id added by default? My posts all have id's without the id column.

Comment: Yes, it is added by default. You have to add a `post_id` to the comments table though.

Comment: That might also be added automatically if you have described the relationship between posts and comments in your migration.

Comment: No, it has been there the whole time. I've added my comments table for reference.

Comment: Can you open up your database to check if the comments have ids?

Comment: Yes checked the database and they all had id's. The solution ended up being to add (@post, comment) after post_comment_path. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

`post_comment_path(:id => comment.id)` can you please try this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your route helper:

```
post_comment_path(@post)
```

must be

```
post_comment_path(comment)
```

You can saw do your comment have id column or not in your `db/schema.rb` file

Comment: Hmm, still getting the same error. I have a comment_id column but no id's are being generated for the comments.

Comment: Please add to question your migration for comment table

Comment: comment_id migration added.